# Accept gzipped body in FastAPI / Uvicorn

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) with [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) to implement a u-service which accepts a json payload in the request's body. Since the request body can be quite large, I wish the service to accept gzipped. How do I accomplish that?

So far the following:

- added the [GZipMiddleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#gzipmiddleware), but it encodes responses, rather that decoding requests
- added a 'Content-Encoding: gzip' to my request

Fail with response:

> Status: 400 Bad Request 
> {     "detail": "There was an error parsing the body" }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FastAPI` documentation [contains](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#create-a-custom-gziprequest-class) an example of a custom gzip encoding request class.

*Note:* This page also contains the following phrase: *"...if you need Gzip support, you can use the provided GzipMiddleware."*, but this is incorrect, since you correctly noticed that middleware only works for responses.

```py
import gzip
from typing import Callable, List

from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute


class GzipRequest(Request):
    async def body(self) -> bytes:
        if not hasattr(self, "_body"):
            body = await super().body()
            if "gzip" in self.headers.getlist("Content-Encoding"):
                body = gzip.decompress(body)
            self._body = body
        return self._body


class GzipRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            request = GzipRequest(request.scope, request.receive)
            return await original_route_handler(request)

        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
app.router.route_class = GzipRoute


@app.post("/sum")
async def sum_numbers(numbers: List[int] = Body(...)):
    return {"sum": sum(numbers)}
```

Comment: hmm. I wonder why implement this as a router and not as a middleware. Is it just for the sake of the example, or are there other considerations?

Comment: It also seems to me that it was for the sake of an example. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1848) for this

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve the same would be like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.types import Message
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
import gzip          
        

class GZipedMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def set_body(self, request: Request):
        receive_ = await request._receive()
        if "gzip" in request.headers.getlist("Content-Encoding"):
            print(receive_)                                     
            data = gzip.decompress(receive_.get('body'))
            receive_['body'] = data

        async def receive() -> Message:
            return receive_

        request._receive = receive                

    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        await self.set_body(request)        
        response = await call_next(request)                
        return response

    

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(GZipedMiddleware)


@app.post("/post")
async def post(req: Request):
    body = await req.body()
    # I'm decoding here in case you just gziped an string
    return body.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Be careful if, like me, you start using this code simply because it is simpler: POSTing content with a fake Content-Length header (bigger than the content actually is) will get your worker to hang until it eventually times out and gets killed by the main process, even if your server is behind nginx and even if the body of the request isn’t gzipped!

Comment: Yes, be very aware of the above comment by Mathieu. This is a nightmare to debug and find.